# C++ Class inheritance in different files

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to learn Inheritance mechanism in C++, I have made a Bancnote(Bills) class, and I want to make a class Card inheriting all the functions and variables from Class Bancnote.

And I get this type of error :

`include\Card.h|6|error: expected class-name before '{' token|`

**BANCNOTE.H**

```
   #ifndef BANCNOTE_H
#define BANCNOTE_H
#include <iostream>

#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;

class Bancnote
{
    public:
        Bancnote();
        Bancnote(string, int ,int ,int );
        ~Bancnote( );
        int getsumacash( );
        void setsumacash( int );
        int getsumaplata( );
        void setsumaplata( int );
        int getrest( );
        void setrest( int );
        string getnume( );
        void setnume( string );
        void ToString();


    protected:

    private:
        string nume;
        int sumacash;
        int rest;
        static int sumaplata;


};

#endif // BANCNOTE_H
```

**BANCNOTE.CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bancnote.h"
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;
int Bancnote::sumaplata=0;

Bancnote::Bancnote(string _nume,int _sumacash,int _rest, int _sumaplata )
{
    this->nume=_nume;
    this->sumacash=_sumacash;
    this->rest=_rest;
    this->sumaplata=_sumaplata;
}

Bancnote::Bancnote()
{
    this->nume="";
    this->sumacash=0;
    this->rest=0;
    this->sumaplata=0;
}

Bancnote::~Bancnote()
{
    cout<<"Obiectul"<<"->" <<this->nume<<"<-"<<"a fost sters cu succes";
}

string Bancnote::getnume()
{
    return nume;
}
void Bancnote::setnume(string _nume)
   {
      this->nume=_nume;
   }
int Bancnote::getsumacash()
{
    return sumacash;
}
void Bancnote::setsumacash(int _sumacash)
{
    this->sumacash=_sumacash;
}
int Bancnote::getsumaplata()
{
    return sumaplata;
}
void Bancnote::setsumaplata(int _sumaplata)
{
    this->sumaplata=_sumaplata;
}
int Bancnote::getrest()
{
    return rest;
}
void Bancnote::setrest(int _rest)
{
    this->rest=_rest;
}
void Bancnote::ToString()
{
    cout<< "-----"<<getnume()<< "-----"<<endl;
    cout<<"Suma Cash: "<<this->getsumacash()<<endl;
    cout<<"Suma spre plata: "<<this->getsumaplata()<<endl;
    cout<<"Restul:"<<this->getrest()<<endl;

}
```

**CARD.H**

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include "Bancnote.h"

class Card: public Bancnote
{
public:
    Card();
    virtual ~Card();

protected:

private:
};

#endif // CARD_H
```

Comment: what is the question? I suppose it is "how to fix the error?", but then we need to see the code. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: also please dont post the "type of error" but the exact error message you get

Comment: `using namespace std;` in a header...

Comment: I don't think a Card is a BankNote. Especially since BankNote has nothing virtual. Your design is wrong. Check the Liskov principle.

Comment: Don't include `card.h` from `bancnote.h`.   The effect of that is trying to derive `Card` from `Bancnote` before `Bancnote` is defined.     Including `bancnote.h` from `card.h` (as you are) is fine, since that gets the order right.

Comment: Get a good C++ book, there are so many bad things with your code :/

Comment: People sometimes "decorate" parameters in order to avoid writing `this->`. There is no point in doing both.

Comment: @molbdnilo in this instance, there is no need, as all arguments should be initialized properly with the initialization list, and the string probably moved.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher  I was referring to the use of both an underscore prefix and `this->` in every function, not just the constructor.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have messed up the includes. What you have is more or less this:

Bancnote.h:

```
#ifndef BANCNOTE_H
#define BANCNOTE_H
#include "Card.h"    // remove this

struct Bancnote {};
#endif
```

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include "Bancnote.h"

struct Card : Bancnote {};   // Bancnote is not yet declared
                             // when compiler reaches here

#endif
```

When in main you include `Bancnote.h` then this header includes `Card.h` so you try to declare `Card` before `Bancnote` is declared. Actually `Bancnote` does not need the definition of `Card`, so simply removing the include should fix it.

PS: there are other issues (see comments below your question). Most importantly it is not clear why a `Card` is a `Bancnote`. Second, never put a `using namespace std;` inside a header! (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why)